# Excel Right and Match Functions

Tags: excel, match

I have a large list of numbers with 8 digits. I'd like to check whether the last 3 digits of an inputted 8 digit number matches with the last 3 digits of any numbers on the list.

I'm using the right function to get the last 3 digits, Right(C2,3), and the match function to match the last 3 digits, Match(K2, D2:D103).

If you look at the picture, it says its matched with list #95 but this is clearly wrong as they all can't match with #95 and $95 is 599. Interestingly, I can't ctrl + f the right() function output number either.

How can I get the match() function to test for whether the last 3 digits match? What's the deal with the right() function output? Why is the match() function not matching correctly?

Picture:
[image: Exel screen shot]

Thank you!

Comment: One reason could be that match will return the first value it finds that match. Since you only match it on 3 numbers.. I guess the number 641 will return multiple of times, but you will only match it on the first row it will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would change your match() function to

```
=match(k2,d2:d203,0)
```

So that it is looking for an exact match.

Near matches can be completed with a 1 in place of the zero.

And, for conciseness, I would also consider:

```
=match(right(c2,3),d2:d103,0)
```

just to save a column of data...

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike! Adding the 0 solved the problem. I thought match() defaulted at 0 but I guess not.

Comment: No, it defaults to 1, as I have found in the past ... if the answer helped, then you can accept it. Cheers anyway.